# Ruby Rails syntax clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

When a model has above definition, what exactly is happening behind the scenes?

My guess is there exists some `validates` method and a parameter is passed with symbol name. What is second parameter? a hash with a value that is hash?

Comment: Does [their documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) on validations tell enough?

Comment: Actually above snippet is from their documentation. I am trying to make sense of Ruby code on   validates method or call to a validate method   class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end

Comment: Check this: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html you can toggle the source.

Comment: Thank you for your effort let me clarify that I understand what it does my question is what it is? is it a hash or way of writing special parameter for rails. I researched and I found it is short cut but still my question is is it a string (which it is not) or hash or key with a block? I am trying to make sense of ruby syntex . Yes I am new to Ruby and trying to make sense of Ruby Syntex may be whoever down voted my question is an expert and my question is simple

Answer (score 1):

First validation `:name` lets know that **Person** is not valid without a **name** attribute.

Second validation `uniqueness`

This helper validates that the attribute's value is **unique** right before the object gets saved. It does not create a uniqueness constraint in the database, so it may happen that two different database connections create two records with the same value for a column that you intend to be unique. To avoid that, you must create a unique index on that column in your database.

Third `{ case_sensitive: false }`

There is also a **case_sensitive** option that you can use to define whether the uniqueness constraint will be case sensitive or not. This option defaults to true

Finally validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

It means in Person model name attribute must be present with uniqueness not be case sensitive.